Unable to Load .FAS File in BricsCAD After Creating Package Installer for Both AutoCAD and BricsCAD
I have created the LISP logic for the BricsCAD and AutoCAD and converted into the .FAS Format and after this I have made the package installer and after installing that package installer I am trying to load and run my .FAS file in the
BricsCAD and for this I am getting errors and Same thing I am trying to load and run on the AutoCAD and there I can Successfully Run this. Can Anyone tell this Why I am getting this Kind of issue?
I have tried to set the registry info for the BricsCAD to run my .FAS file but not able to get the desired output.

.fas encryption of AutoLISP files is proprietary to Autodesk, and consequently, such files can only be loaded on AutoCAD.
BricsCAD uses its own .des encryption format which can be obtained for a given AutoLISP file either using the options provided by the BLADE IDE in BricsCAD, or using the DESCoder.exe application included with the BrisCAD installation.
More information can be found here.
